# Search function in PHP works with numeric values but doesn't work with letters/words

Tags: php, mysql, numeric, alphabetical

People can order links at my platform and these get stored in two different tables, eg wp_project and wp_articles. The reason for this is that when people place an order for 1 link one project row gets created and one article row gets created.

However if a client orders 10 links there will be one project entry and ten article entries. Now this isn't very relevant to my problem but just to explain how the system works.

There are two common identifiers for projects and articles, both the ID and the project title are stored in both inpu_project and inpu_articles.

Now if I want to echo all the links from one project I built a search function where I can select the project ID, click search and whether a client ordered 1 link or 20 links that amount of links will show.

The problem starts when I want to search based on the project title instead of ID, which is non-numeric but just words (with spaces in between sometimes).

This to prevent the error undefined index in my error logs

```
    $where_clouse='';
```

This is the search function based on the project title:

```
    if(isset($_GET['todo']) && $_GET['todo']=='search')
    {
        if($_GET['proid']!=0){
            $where_clouse.=' AND P.`project_title`='.$_GET['proid'];
        }
    }
```

This is the database query to pull the links from it:

```
    $sql="SELECT P.`project_title`, P.`backlink` FROM `inpu_articles` AS P 
WHERE P.`post_it_posted` = '1' ".$where_clouse."  ORDER BY P.`project_title`  ASC";
    $backlinks=$wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

This is the actual search function that triggers the first code I pasted:

```
    <p>Select a project title and hit search!</p>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="todo" id="todo" value="search" />
        <select name="proid" id="proid">
        <option value="0">All Projects</option>
        <?php $projects=getTitles(); foreach($projects as $project){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $project['title']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_GET['proid']) && $_GET['proid']==$project['title'] ) { echo 'selected="selected"';  } ?> ><?php echo $project['title'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input class="submit_search" type="submit" id="search_button" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

And this is the code that pulls the project titles from the project table:

```
    function getTitles($where=false)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql="SELECT  `title`, `link` FROM `inpu_project` WHERE `link`='1' ORDER BY `title` ASC";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
        return $result;
    }
```

All pretty straight forward and it works 100% fine if I replace the non-numeric title in the code for both the inpu_articles and the inpu_project tables with the numeric id.

Then the code does exactly what it does, but when I use the project title instead it just shows ALL of the links that every client ever ordered and no error shows up in my database. It's like it can't find a match or something, which is plain weird.

So am I missing something here? Is it not possible to match words or is there something that I should adjust when using words instead of numeric values?

Lastly, for what it's worth, this is the code that echos the query:

```
    <?php foreach ($backlinks as $backlink) {
        $backlink_overview=$backlink['backlink'];
    ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $backlink_overview; ?></li>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

The titles do show up in my form / search drop down menu so I am surprised it can't match the project title with the title that's stored in the article table.

My gut says this is where it goes wrong:

```
    P.`project_title`='.$_GET['proid'];
```

But it doesn't throw any syntax errors or any errors whatsoever, it just shows all the links that are stored in the inpu_article table, ignorning my search function altogether.

Comment: Did you enable PHP warnings and errors in your code? If not, you can do so by putting `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php code. This way you'll be able to see any warning and errors.

Comment: What is this conditional statement `if($_GET['proid']!=0)` about? I'm guessing this is your problem. Non numeric inputs does not fall in this condition, I think. Then you will get all data because the where clause does not test the title.

Comment: I added the code but no additonal errors show up. I made a temp fix by echoing the project title in the select form drop down list, while comparing the ID instead. This works of course and it's easier for me to identify a project by the title instead of the ID but I find it very strange that it isn't able to match text fields instead of INT fields.

Comment: N Moeini, when I remove if($_GET['proid']!=0 I get a very strange error, saying it can't find the column mysewingproject in where clause. But there's not even a table named where clause (nor did I state these words anywhere in my code) and mysewingproject is the project title, not a column at all.

Comment: I do think you have a point about this if($_GET['proid']!=0), could you show me how to adjust it for non-numeric inputs?

Comment: Try to change it like `if(isset($_GET['proid']) && !empty($_GET['proid'])){
            $where_clouse.=" AND P.project_title='$_GET['proid']'";
        }` . Here I changed the `$where_clause` slightly too.

Comment: I tried to fix it by putting if(!isempty($_GET['proid'])) but this throws the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function isempty() in /home/denrevie/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/findlinks.php on line 34

Comment: Makes it even worse N Moeini:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/denrevie/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/findlinks.php on line 35

Comment: I will try your suggestion without modifying the $where_clouse

Comment: Instead of showing the whole list of links while searching it shows nothing after replacing it with: if(isset($_GET['proid']) && !empty($_GET['proid'])) - once again no errors show up!

Comment: Sorry, now we do have the following error: [12-Sep-2017 04:01:57 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'Armchair' in 'where clause' for query SELECT P.`project_title`, P.`project_id`, P.`backlink`, P.`post_it_posted` FROM `inpu_articles` AS P 
    WHERE P.`post_it_posted` = '1'  AND P.`project_title`=Armchair  ORDER BY P.`project_id`  ASC made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/seoexp/findlinks.php')

Comment: Did you applied my change in sql? That's the point of the error.

Comment: No I haven't done anything inside sql, if you mean inside phpmyadmin, I just replaced my code with yours and tried a handful of other variations using double quotes, single quotes, removing the backticks and what not, currently this is the code I put cause you forgot one closing bracket:  if(isset($_GET['proid'])) {
  $where_clouse.=' AND P.`project_title`='.$_GET['proid'];
 } and this throws the unknown colum armchair in where clause.

Comment: Apologies, you didn't forget a closing bracket, I read that wrong, but problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the condition for `where_clause` and the `where_clause` itself.
To check for input you need to check if the parameter is set and is not empty. Then for where clause you need to put the string into quotes. Change that part of the code like bellow

```
if(isset($_GET['proid']) && !empty($_GET['proid'])){ 
      $where_clouse.=" AND P.project_title='".$_GET['proid']."'"; 
  }
```

Comment: Didn't see this comment, will try this now!

Comment: Problem FIXED :) Thank you so much, no clue about all those extra quotes but it now executes perfectly with the following statement: SELECT P.project_title, P.project_id, P.backlink, P.post_it_posted FROM inpu_articles AS P WHERE P.post_it_posted='1' AND P.project_title='Armchair' ORDER BY P.project_id ASC

Comment: I see 3 quotes in a row and it confused me completely but now I see what you did, you put it like: '".$_GET['proid']."' - once again thanks a million. I will remember this for future cases. Still quite baffled that it worked with INT as the comparison field but I guess that's how PHP works :)

Comment: Glad that it fixed your problem. The problem was that in mysql strings must be in quote otherwise it considers them column name but it accepts integers. All those single and double quotes are required to properly create a valid query from php variable

Comment: I don't see any option to accept the answer, there's only a button at the bottom that says Answer your question. I clicked vote up a couple of times but it looks like I need to have 15 reputation points for that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can be wrong in SQL statement. And you can print the sql string statement to the screen and copy it into Mysql to check. I hope you can find your mistake.

Comment: This is not an answer IMHO. It is more like a comment.

Comment: tks for your advise =)

Comment: If the SQL statement would be wrong I assume it would show up in my error_log like usual, I've seen plenty of such errors during my trials and errors.

Comment: you print it and copy here i will check to help you

Comment: Currently after the adjustments of what we discussed above this is what gets shown: [12-Sep-2017 04:29:10 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'DennisH' in 'where clause' for query SELECT P.project_title, P.project_id, P.backlink, P.post_it_posted FROM inpu_articles AS P 
    WHERE P.post_it_posted='1'  AND P.project_title=DennisH  ORDER BY P.project_id  ASC made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/seoexp/findlinks.php')

Comment: $sql="SELECT P.project_title, P.project_id, P.backlink, P.post_it_posted FROM inpu_articles AS P 
    WHERE P.post_it_posted='1' ".$where_clouse."  ORDER BY P.project_id  ASC";

Comment: i saw it WordPress database error Unknown column 'DennisH'. You must put DennisH into ' like this 'DennisH'

Comment: I just printed it on my screen using echo $sql and it shows like this now: SELECT P.project_title, P.project_id, P.backlink, P.post_it_posted FROM inpu_articles AS P WHERE P.post_it_posted='1' ORDER BY P.project_id ASC

Comment: As you can see it completely ignores the $where_clouse now

Comment: SELECT P.project_title, P.project_id, P.backlink, P.post_it_posted FROM inpu_articles AS P WHERE P.post_it_posted='1' ' AND P.project_title=Armchair' ORDER BY P.project_id ASC

Comment: This is the result of changing ". $where_clouse ." to '" .$where_clouse ."'

Comment: How can I get quotes around DennisH or Amrchair based on this code: $where_clouse.=' AND P.project_title='.$_GET['proid'];

Comment: @DennisHamming, did you try my answer? It should fix the problem with sql

Comment: The strangest part of all is, how come this query executes perfectly when I use an INT field to compare, and now it completely breaks when I use text fields to compare, while it's the exact same SQL query.

Comment: I don't know how to get single quotes around DennisH, eg 'DennisH'